# "httpd -k restart" has killed my website... How to debug?

Tags: apache-2.2, website

so I broke my business' website, doing a stupid sanity check command that failed. We can discuss why I chose to sanity check apache like this.

How would I go about debugging this problem? Here are my observations on the situation:

- httpd -k restart works
- the vps*.host.com still resolves
- the website won't resolve
- ping www.WEBSITE.com still works

whm-server-status

> Apache Status
>
> ## Apache Server Status
>   for 127.0.0.1
>
> Server Version: Apache/2.2.15
>   (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15
>   OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2
>   mod_auth_passthrough/2.1
>   mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
>   SVN/1.6.2
>
> Server Built: Mar
>   29 2010 12:52:34
>
> ---
>
> Current Time: Monday, 05-Jul-2010
>   15:46:47 PDT
>
> Restart Time:
>   Monday, 05-Jul-2010 15:42:33 PDT
>
> Parent Server Generation: 0
>
> Server uptime:  4 minutes 13
>   seconds
>
> Total accesses: 2 -
>   Total Traffic: 0 kB
>
> CPU
>   Usage: u0 s0 cu0 cs0
>
> .00791
>   requests/sec - 0 B/second - 0
>   B/request
>
> 1 requests
>   currently being processed, 5 idle
>   workers
>
> ```
> W_..........................................................
> ................................................................
> ................................................................
> ................................................................
> ```
>
> Scoreboard Key:
>   "**`_`**" Waiting for
>   Connection,  "**`S`**"
>   Starting up,  "**`R`**"
>   Reading Request,
>   "**`W`**" Sending Reply,
>   "**`K`**" Keepalive
>   (read),  "**`D`**" DNS
>   Lookup,
>  "**`C`**"
>   Closing connection, 
>   "**`L`**" Logging, 
>   "**`G`**" Gracefully
>   finishing,
>  
>   "**`I`**" Idle cleanup
>   of worker,  "**`.`**"
>   Open slot with no current process
>
> SrvPIDAccMCPU SSReqConnChildSlotClientVHostRequest
>
> **0-0**30980/1/1_ 0.009400.00.000.00
>   127.0.0.1vps1.host.comGET / HTTP/1.0
>
> **1-0**30990/1/1_ 0.0054530.00.000.00
>   99.107.235.0vps1.host.comGET /whm-server-status
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> **2-0**31010/0/0**W**
>   0.00000.00.000.00
>   127.0.0.1vps1.host.comGET /whm-server-status
>   HTTP/1.0
>
> ---
>
> SrvChild Server
>   number - generation 
>   PIDOS process
>   ID 
>   AccNumber of accesses
>   this connection / this child / this
>   slot  MMode
>   of operation
>   CPUCPU usage, number
>   of seconds
>   SSSeconds since
>   beginning of most recent
>   request 
>   ReqMilliseconds
>   required to process most recent
>   request 
>   ConnKilobytes
>   transferred this connection 
>   ChildMegabytes
>   transferred this child 
>   SlotTotal megabytes
>   transferred this slot
>
> ---
>
> **SSL/TLS Session
>   Cache Status:** 
>    cache type:
>   **DBM**, maximum size:
>   **unlimited**
> current sessions:
>   **0**, current size: **0**
>   bytes
> average session size:
>   **0** bytes

Comment: Please don't "mark" your question as fixed in the title - Accepting an answer automatically marks the question answered.  (Similarly putting "Emergency" in your title doesn't buy you anything - Every problem is an "emergency" to the person its happening to :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried accessing your site and all non-HTTPS requests to `www.website.com` are being redirected to the same URL but with an `https` scheme, e.g.

```
http://www.website.com/ -> https://www.website.com
```

But the HTTPS port on your server (port 443) is closed, which means there's no server listening on it (which is what you'd need to be handling HTTPS requests).

I'm guessing that the server should not be redirecting regular HTTP requests to HTTPS. You should try to figure out why it's doing that and fix it. Usually this sort of thing is done with a directive like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com\1
```

somewhere in the Apache configuration.

If you really do mean to serve your entire site over HTTPS, you will need to add

```
Listen 443
```

in the configuration file.

Comment: Fixed it per your instruction. What's weird is that I already have a block of code that seems to do just that. {<IfDefine SSL> Listen 0.0.0.0:443; AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt; AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl .crl; </IfDefine>}

Comment: Yep, that block of code you quoted will get Apache to listen on port 443, but only if the `SSL` Apache environment variable is defined. You could define it by passing the `-DSSL` option to Apache when you start it up (if you wanted to have an HTTPS site). This is an easy way to conditionally enable or disable all the different parts of the configuration that relate to HTTPS.

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad you got it working again :-)

Answer (score 2):

First: Check the error logs - maybe at /var/log/apache/error_log (or /etc/httpd/logs/error_log)